# how to enable two independant touchpoints in qt

Tags: android, c++, qt

android: 2.3.7
smartphone: HTC DESIRE
framework : qt necessitas
C++

I have created clone of space invaders on android with Qt(necessitas port to Android). For moving left and right I use touchpoints from QTouchEvent.
Problem is :: When left side of screen is pressed , ship goes left(primary touch point) , finger stays on screen and right side is touched(second point) , ship goes right , then the left finger is released  and ship stops because primary touchpoint is detached and pull with self hole line of points out of the game (second point in this case). So second touch dont exists even in that moment , right finger is on screen.
Thats the way of toucpoint organization in Qt. Second point dont receve events.
I try with QGestures but fails on some steps with same reasons.
Any help would be appreciate.

I just want some keyboard features from desktop on smartphone.
Eg. left arrow pressed - > ship left  , right arrow pressed withot left is released -> ship right , left released -> ship right because right is active  and recieve events.

Comment: Not familiar with the qt, but on the press and release events, can you just toggle some flags to indicate a direction to move instead of including the logic for control?

Comment: Flags are allredy involved.Pressed left side of screen -> flag moveLeft is switched and ship goes left thru game loop , thats no issue. Problem is on the end of my post when left is released and right stays down. In that moment flag is moveRight but with no further control because right dont recieve events so if right finger goes out of screen , flag stays moveRight insted stop :: right is inactive (not exist for sistem because primary point(left in this case) is detached(left finger goes from screen). Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's what I wasn't sure of - so there is no onrelease() kind of event handler in qt then?

Comment: there is only one Primary touchPoint. Let it be LEFT. If finger is on left side down - left is active , after is pressed RIGHT and became seecond point in Qt toucPoints grouping. Because of this rule , after left finger is elevate , RIGHT is dead. No metter if finger is down or up -> that toucPoint is over and you dont have any control till new primary touch is created. More of this topic on :: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtouchevent.html

Comment: It also say ::Note that on some systems, it is possible to receive touch events without a primary touch point. But how to enable that , on my HTC desire is 100% infrastructure for that because all java aps from google play have independant touchs. I use c++ with Qt so , thats very powerfull , should be easy...

Comment: it seems like bug :: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16772